# URLSession test case

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I have a user authentication test case that registers user and user is saved in a json file. The whole project is about test and I cannot seem to understand how to go about it.

There is a NetworkService.swift file which handles all test functions but a url was not supplied to call register.

**NetworkService.swift**

```
class NetworkService: NSObject {

    private let session: URLSession

    init(session: URLSession) {
        self.session = session
    }

    //token for requests
    var authToken: String?


    //MARK: Singleton

    static var sharedService: NetworkService = NetworkService(session: URLSessionMock())


    //MARK: Requests

    func registerUserWith(login: String?, password: String?, success: @escaping (Data)->(), failure: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {

        //register user method, use self.session
    }

    func getAllEvents(success: @escaping (Data)->(), failure: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {

        //get all events method, use self.session
    }

    func subscribeOnEvent(eventUUID: Int, success: @escaping (Data)->(), failure: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {

        //subscribe method, use self.session
    }

    func unsubscribeFromEvent(eventUUID: Int, success: @escaping (Data)->(), failure: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {

        //unsubscribe method, use self.session
    }
}
```

This is a test case

```
func testUserRegistrationMethod() {
        let expectation: XCTestExpectation = self.expectation(description: "user registration")

        let login: String = "testUser"
        let password: String = "pass"

        NetworkService.sharedService.registerUserWith(login: login, password: password, success: { (responseData) in
            expectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssertNotNil(responseData, "Data is nil")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:[]) as! [String : Any?]
                let authToken: String = json["authToken"] as! String

                XCTAssertNotNil(authToken, "AuthToken is nil")

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }) { (error) in
            expectation.fulfill()
            XCTFail((error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 4) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
```

You are working on the application for Conferences. A user of such application should be able to register on this application and interact with it on browsing the available events, be able to subscribe and unsubscribe from the current conference.

Implement a network service that is used to interact with the server.

**Problem Statement**

You have to implement the following methods:

- The function registers users with a login and a password. In case of a successful registration, it returns the token in a success block. In case of an error, it calls a failure block.

  `func registerUserWith(login: String?, password: String?, success: @escaping (Data)->(), failure: @escaping (Error?) -> ())`

I am not supplied with a url and do not know if this is a complete question

Comment: The test for it has been written. it is the function `registerUserWith` that is the problem now

Comment: Okay Thanks. Really appreciate @matt

Comment: @matt, yes they expect to write all the 4 funcs without any url, when they say use self.session means to use that instance but if we do start a dataTask with that, to create  a post httpMethod idk, seems weird. Matt do you recommend us any tutorial to build this kind of scenario? with token